# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, set, tuples

I keep getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Jake\SkyDrive\Documents\_Jake's Documents\School\2013 Fall\CSCI\Final Project\word_game.py", line 57, in callback
if len(input_set & user_set) == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'tuple'
```

'user_set' is a combination of four sets. Is that why it's giving me this?

Comment: `user_set` appears to be a `tuple`.  Show the code that generated it.

Comment: Define "combination of four sets". It's a tuple.

Comment: [works on my machine](http://ideone.com/4iJzX8). Please provide a complete example that replicates your problem.

Comment: user_set = (mcw_set, lcw_set, uw_set, rw_set).

I was told on here to use this code to award points based on intersections. So for example for each input_set and mcw_set intersection it would add 1 point per intersection to user score. for each input_set and lcw_set intersection it would add 2 points per intersection to user score. and so on, up to 4 points per intersection for input_set and rw_set intersections. Is there a better way to do it?

for multiplier, user_set in enumerate(user_sets, 1):
    user_score += len(input_set & user_set) * multiplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to compare input_set with all items in user_set, so may be this is what your want:

```
import operator
if len(input_set & reduce(operator.__or__, user_set)) == 0:
```

Let's say

```
user_set = (set([1, 2]), set([3, 4]))
```

then reduce(operator_*or*_, user_set) will return

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: That got rid of the first error, but I got a new one with this line

    for multiplier, user_set in enumerate(user_sets, 1):
        user_score += len(input_set & reduce(operator.__or__, user_set)) * multiplier

NameError: global name 'user_sets' is not defined

If I make it 'user_set' I get:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'int'

Comment: @musicfiend122 You only show user_set, there is no user_sets, hope it is a typo

Comment: I think it is saying that reduce(operator.__or__, user_set) is an 'int', but I don't know why

Comment: @musicfiend122 show your user_set content or just print reduce(operator.__or__, user_set) to see what is it. You have every thing, don't think, do sth